# Краевая задача для дифференциального уравнения второго порядка

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь разобраться в численном дифференцировании. И передо мной стоит задачу решить "краевую задачу".[image: ну воот]

Собственно проблема насколько мне известно,где-то в решении, мы должны решить СЛАУ одним из методов. У меня есть готовый Гаусс. По каким значения нужно строить матрицу? Вот наработки:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] T = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        List<double> y = new List<double>();
        List<double> y_e = new List<double>();
        List<double> e = new List<double>();
        //y[0] = 0;
        //y_e[0] = 0;
        double j = 1;
        for (double i = 0.01; i < 0.04; i += 0.01)
        {
            y.Add(DoubleDiff(j, ref i) + j * j * (Diff(F(j) * (j - T[Convert.ToInt32(j)]), ref i)) + j * j * j * (F(j) * (j - T[Convert.ToInt32(j)])));
            y_e.Add(16 * Math.Pow(j, 3) * (j - i));
            j++;
        }


        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < T.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + 1 + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < T.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(y[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < T.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(y_e[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < y.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Add(y_e[i] - y[i]);
            Console.Write(e[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    static double F(double x)
    {
        return 16 * Math.Pow(x, 3);
    }

    static double Diff(double x, ref double index)//производная первого порядка
    {
        return (F(Convert.ToInt32(x) + index) - F(Convert.ToInt32(x) - index)) / (2 * index);
    }

    static double DoubleDiff(double x, ref double index)//производная второго порядка
    {
        return (F(Convert.ToInt32(x) + index) - 2 * F(Convert.ToInt32(x)) + F(Convert.ToInt32(x) - index)) / Math.Pow(index, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны в своем д.у. заменить все производные их на разностные аналоги. Приводите после подстановки подобные слагаемые и получите СЛАУ.
Разностный аналог второй производной: (y[k+1]-2y[k]+y[k-1]) / (h^2) +x [k]*y[k]=0.
h - шаг разностной сетки. Аналог первой производной: (y[k+1]-y[k-1])/(2h).
преобразовали д.у., разбили отрезочек и формируете СЛАУ, куда и подставите значения сетки [0..n]

Comment: Ну я заменил, в цикле их. Но у меня выходит одномерный массив,или предлагаете в двумерном вычислять?

Comment: @AlexPark совокупность уравнений является обычной двумерной матрицей, не понимаю, откуда проблема

Comment: Belaev не особо понимаю,где мне взять совокупность уравнений? если по условию,она не дана,есть только д.у.,какими данными заполнить матрицу? Неужели брать из головы любые?

Comment: и ещё правильно ли я написал производную 2-ого порядка? @VanyaBelyaev

Comment: @AlexPark так у вас есть отрезок, на котором располагается разностная сетка. значения из этого отрезка должны подставляться в разностные аналоги д.у, поэтому уравнений много. Производная 2-ого порядка аппроксимируется немного не так. Поправлю ответ выше (не в комментах, посмотрите)

Comment: так,если я правильно понял,например у меня отрезок от 0 до 16, я подставляю свой f(x) ,где x- у меня будет элемент от 0 до 16. т.е. 16 эл-ов тогда можно построить матрицу 4х4, а матрица будет содержать значения f(x) ? @VanyaBelyaev

Comment: @AlexPark в матрицу иксы из отрезка, ну)

Comment: и там же изменять их на y(x)? А потом для изменённой матрицы, использовать Гаусса?

Comment: Так, вопрос по начальной формуле краевой, V*x^3(x-T) , где T- отрезок от 0 до 16. А x - разве не значение из T? @VanyaBelyaev